# server thread could not see changed fields of a serialized object

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream

I'm facing with a problem about sending and receiving serialized object via TCP sockets. Actually, i can receive/send an object properly between a server thread and client thread.However, the issue is if a changed a property's value of a received/send object ,this change couldn't be realized by the waiting thread. Consider this code sample;

```
public class ClientThread extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {

ClientObject mainClient; // Initiliazed after sockets connect to server successfully
.
.
.
      String addNewBuddy = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter the Username of the person who you want to add...");

      mainClient.setBuddyRequest(true);
      mainClient.setBuddyRequestAccount(addNewBuddy);

      send.writeObject(mainClient); // write into an ObjectOutputStream
      send.flush(); // flush it

      System.out.println("mainClient.setBuddyRequest : " + mainClient.isBuddyRequest() + " setBuddyRequestAccount : " + mainClient.getBuddyRequestAccount()); // Check if values changed properly

      ClientObject tempClientObject; // temporary an instance of ClientObject

      while(( tempClientObject = (ClientObject) receive.readObject()) != null){

           if( !tempClientObject.isBuddyRequest() ){

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Buddy Request Information", "Requested buddy doesnt exist!!!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                }

                else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Buddy Request Information", "Requested buddy added into your buddy list succesfully", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    labelSetText = tempClientObject.getNickName();
                    onlineStatus = tempClientObject.isIsOnline();
                    model.addElement(createPanel());
                }

            }
.
.
.
}
```

So after i changed some properties of `mainClient` i send it to server. Here is the part which server thread waits an object to give some reaction. Moreover, when client sends second object (which makes counter bigger than 0) server thread can read it without errors but i recognize that even client send a modified object as a second message to server there are no differences between properties of first and second object!.

```
        while( ( clientO = (ClientObject) receive.readObject()) != null ){

                counterMessage++;

                 if( counterMessage==1) { // 

                     checkAccountIfExist(toWrite,file.exists(),toModify,clientO); // Check is connected account exist in database of server

                 } // end of if (counter==1)

                 else{ // Second time when server waits 

// prints counter=2 but clientO.isBuddyRequest printed as 'false' 
//instead of 'true' so this makes if statement unreachable!
                     System.out.println("Counter = " + counterMessage + "  BUDDYREQUEST : " + clientO.isBuddyRequest() + " USERNAME : " + clientO.getUserName());

                     if(clientO.isBuddyRequest()){
                         System.out.println("Entered");
                         checkBuddyAvalaible(clientO);
                     }

                 }

        }
```

and finally my serializlible ClientObject's code

```
public class ClientObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8662836292460365873L;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String nickName;
    private String message;
    private boolean checkAcc;
    private LinkedList<ClientObject> buddyList;
    private boolean isOnline;
    private boolean buddyRequest;
    private String buddyRequestAccount;

    public ClientObject(String userName, String password){

        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.checkAcc = false;
        this.buddyList = new LinkedList<ClientObject>();
        this.isOnline = false;
        this.buddyRequest = false;
        this.buddyRequestAccount = null;
    }

   ...methods of getters and setters
}
```

I hope i had been clear about the issue and i will appreciated for every answer, well thanks anyway.

Comment: Show the code where you are serializing and sending the object of `ClientObject`

Comment: here is the link i didn't put the whole code cause it's a little bit complex. `mainClient` is type of ClientObject and in this code sample it is the first time it get initialized and sent to server.

http://codepaste.net/o8d8o6

Comment: And the code you send the object for the second time?

Comment: http://codepaste.net/pszwoz link for where i set two fields of main object before send it to server. As you can see `setBuddyRequest` and `setBuddyRequestAccount` were changed before it was send.

http://codepaste.net/u4jfiy link of while statement of server thread where it waits for receive an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is call ObjectOutputStream.reset(), or use writeUnshared().

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are writing the sending code :

```
.....
mainClient = new ClientObject(userName, password);
String clientNickName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter your NickName");
mainClient.setNickName(clientNickName);
send.writeObject(mainClient);
send.flush();
......
```

In a loop. If it is so , You should read this fact about java serialization:

> While performing serialization of objects, Java forms a data structure
>   similar to an Object Graph to determine which objects need to be
>   serialized. It starts from the main object to serialize, and
>   recursively traverses all the objects reachable from the main object.
>   For each object that it encounters, which needs serialization, it
>   associates an identifier that marks the object as already been
>   serialized to the given ObjectOutputStream instance. So when Java
>   encounters the same object that has already been marked as serialized
>   to the ObjectOutputStream, it does not serialize the object again,
>   rather a handle to the same object is serialized. This is how Java
>   avoids having to re-serialize an already serialized object.

**EDIT**
 On the basis of *EJP's comment* I have updated the post to give correct message to the OPs.
After first time you send an object of `ClientObject` to the `OutputStream` via `ObjectOutputStream`, next time when you send the changed object of `ClientObject` java checks if the object of this type is already being serialized . Since it has already been serialized so , java does'nt serialize the new `object` created again. And that's why you are getting same object at other side. 
The rememdy to this problem is that each time you want to send the changed object of `ClientObject` reset the `ObjectOutputStream` like:

```
send.reset();
```

And then send the changed object to other end.

Comment: So i guess at the same time i have to reinitialize the `ObjectInputStream` as like `ObjectOutputStream` when i'm waiting for an object ? (even in while statements like `while(( tempClientObject = (ClientObject) receive.readObject()) != null)` )

Comment: umm..No ..I don't think that it is needed... Just reinitialize the `ObjectOutputStream` only for each loop.

Comment: well i'm trying but compiler gets stuck in somewhere. Do i need to close outputstreams everytime after i send the object ?

Comment: Yes you should close the outputStreams

Comment: ok i recognize that whenever i closed `send` (which is initialized like `send = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())` and also `send` is declared globally in the class) the `ObjectInputStream` of the opposite side gets stuck like in a dead loop. So how can i handle with this because server and client waits an object in a while loop which is like `while(( tempClientObject = (ClientObject) receive.readObject()) != null){`.

Comment: can you put your all codes for server and client?  I would like to test them myself..

Comment: ClientThread --> http://codepaste.net/bt6d9r
Server --> http://codepaste.net/fqsjit
ClientHandler --> http://codepaste.net/in6rrr
ClientObject --> http://codepaste.net/tzozgj . I add a little bit description of whole classes even more if you want i can upload the project

Comment: @quartaela: Have a look at my Edit, I have pasted an example for this scenario. I hope this would be of your help.

Comment: so your point is send/receive an object in while statement like `while(true)` ? and also thanks for all your replies.

Comment: @VishalK You've identified the problem correctly, but your solution is using a sledgehammer to kill a flea. All he needs is ObjectOutputStream.reset().

Comment: @EJP : I am just surprised that this method could do the same thing indeed.. Thanks for really being a life saver!!..And yeah I deserve this downvote...